# Extracting str from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I read csv file into a dataframe named df

Each rows contains str below.

> {"name":"Daniel Gimness","id":10551043...}

I would like to extract "name" and "id" from each row and make a new dataframe to store the str.

I tried several ways to do it but all failed and below is the outcome of one of my attempts. Please let me know if there is any suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thanks

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.creator.tolist())
```

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 934 935 936 937 938 939 940 941 942 943
0   {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
1   {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
2   {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
3   {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
4   {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
195609  {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
195610  {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
195611  {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
195612  {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
195613  {   "   u   r   l   s   "   :   {   "   ... None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex expression with [`pandas.Series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Something like:

```
df["id"] = df["creator"].str.extract(""" "id":"([0-9]+)" """)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've Json data in column `"creator"`. You can try:

```
import json

x = df["creator"].apply(
    lambda x: {"name": (m := json.loads(x))["name"], "id": m["id"]}
)
print(pd.DataFrame(x.to_list()))
```

Prints:

```
                name        id
0     Daniel Gimness  10551043
1  Redmond Entwistle  10551043

...
```